# a pythonic way to write a constrain() function

Tags: python

What's the best way of writing a constrain function? or is there already a builtin python function that does this?

**Option 1:**

```
def constrain(val, min_val, max_val):

    if val < min_val: return min_val
    if val > max_val: return max_val
    return val
```

**Option 2:**

```
def constrain(val, min_val, max_val):

    if val < min_val: 
        val = min_val

    elif val > max_val: 
        val = max_val

    return val
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I do not know if this is the more "pythonic", but you can use built-in [`min()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) and [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) like this:

```
def constrain(val, min_val, max_val):
    return min(max_val, max(min_val, val))
```

Answer (score 5):

In case you need to do this for a lot of numbers (arrays full of them), you should probably be using Numpy, which has a built-in [clip](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html) function. For simple Python programs, go with Delgan's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34837691/2647279).

Comment: "For simple Python programs, go with Delgan's answer." - Why not use  `clip()` always?

Comment: @Fermiparadox because you typically don't want to have the enormous Numpy library as a dependency for a simple script, it is not part of the standard library. Also the return type will be a Numpy scalar, which should normally work as expected, but this might not be what you want when working with Python decimals or fractions.

Answer (score 1):

If you can process a bunch of values at a time, you might try a list comprehension:

```
a = [1,1,5,1,1]
b = [7,2,8,5,3]
c = [3,3,3,3,3]
[min(y,max(x,z)) for x,y,z in zip(a, b, c)]

[3, 2, 5, 3, 3]
```

or even NumPy:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array(a)
b = np.array(b)
c = np.array(c)

np.minimum(b, np.maximum(a, c))
np.minimum(b, np.maximum(a, 3))  # just use 3 if they are all the same

c.clip(a, b)    # or just use NumPy's clip method
np.clip(c, a, b)

array([3, 2, 5, 3, 3])
array([3, 2, 5, 3, 3])
array([3, 2, 5, 3, 3])
array([3, 2, 5, 3, 3])
```

Comment: Oh @BasSwinckels got there first!